# sbt fetches the ivy*.xml files and the jars dependencies but not the jar itself

Tags: jar, compilation, sbt

I have mentioned a jar(belonging to my org's artifactory) in my build.sbt file

```
lazy val core =
  module("core", deps = Seq(
    "io.swagger" % "swagger-annotations" % "1.5.8"
  )).settings(
      libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
        "com.quantcast" % "quantserve_shared" % "latest.integration"
      ))
```

When i compile the code, i see these files getting downloaded in my ~/.ivy2 directory but not the jars folder or any jar.

```
ls ./cache/com.quantcast/quantserve_shared/
ivy-3.5.3132.xml                        ivy-3.5.3132.xml.original               ivydata-3.5.3132.properties             ivydata-latest.integration.properties
```

I checked my resolution-cache/reports/audience-link-core-audience-link-core_2.11-compile-internal.xml  file and see this :

```
<module organisation="com.quantcast" name="quantserve_shared">
            <revision name="3.5.3132" status="release" pubdate="20170315145341" resolver="sbt-chain" artresolver="sbt-chain" downloaded="false" searched="true" default="false" conf="compile, default(compile)" position="74">
                <metadata-artifact status="no" details="" size="7161" time="0" location="/Users/pkhurana/.ivy2/cache/com.quantcast/quantserve_shared/ivy-3.5.3132.xml" searched="true" origin-is-local="false" origin-location="http://<My org artifactory>/libs-bmr-releases-local/com/quantcast/quantserve_shared/3.5.3132/ivy-3.5.3132.xml"/>
                <caller organisation="audience-link-core" name="audience-link-core_2.11" conf="compile-internal, compile, provided, optional" rev="latest.integration" rev-constraint-default="latest.integration" rev-constraint-dynamic="latest.integration" callerrev="0.9999999.17.76.111418"/>
                <artifacts>
                </artifacts>
            </revision>
        </module>
```

So nothing comes in artifactory tag, but i do see other jars which are dependencies of quantserve_shared jar gets downloaded and their entry in the resolution cache also fine.

```
<module organisation="com.twitter.util-core" name="util-core">
            <revision name="1.12.13" status="release" pubdate="20131024042503" resolver="sbt-chain" artresolver="sbt-chain" homepage="" downloaded="false" searched="false" default="false" conf="default, compile, runtime, master" position="127">
                <metadata-artifact status="no" details="" size="2240" time="0" location="/Users/pkhurana/.ivy2/cache/com.twitter.util-core/util-core/ivy-1.12.13.xml" searched="false" origin-is-local="true" origin-location="/Users/pkhurana/.ivy2/quantcast-bmr/com.twitter.util-core/util-core/ivy-1.12.13.xml"/>
                <caller organisation="com.quantcast" name="quantserve_shared" conf="compile" rev="1.12.13" rev-constraint-default="1.12.13" rev-constraint-dynamic="1.12.13" callerrev="3.5.3132"/>
                <artifacts>
                    <artifact name="util-core" type="jar" ext="jar" status="no" details="" size="632306" time="0" location="/Users/pkhurana/.ivy2/quantcast-bmr/com.twitter.util-core/util-core/jars/util-core-1.12.13.jar">
                        <origin-location is-local="true" location="/Users/pkhurana/.ivy2/quantcast-bmr/com.twitter.util-core/util-core/jars/util-core-1.12.13.jar"/>
                    </artifact>
                </artifacts>
            </revision>
        </module>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the dependency jar did not have the configuration 'compile' specified in its ivy file. It has 'master' specified with visibility public. Now sbt tries to find 'compile' by default but fails.
This got solved by changing it to

`"com.quantcast" % "quantserve_shared" % "3.5.3166" % "compile->master"`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why but the latest sbt (0.13.15) does download everything